# Will it break the alliance, if I take over a worker-occupied area?

Tags: scythe

In [Scythe](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/169786/scythe), [The Rise of Fenris](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/242277/scythe-rise-fenris), in campaign mode episode 2 on the peace-track, it's possible to create alliances with other players.

The alliance is broken if one member of the alliance attacks the other.

But does it count as an attack if I move a character or mech into an allied area occupied only by a worker, no mech or character?

The worker is just sent home, there is no attack-action phase involved.

I'm thinking it shouldn't break the alliance, but I'm having doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving into an area occupied by a worker, it counts as an attack.  From the rules:

> If you ever attack a player who has your faction’s Alliance
>   token or force their workers off a territory, you must flip over
>   the [alliance] token you have.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure we'd missed something. Glad I stuck with my instincts and didn't force the worker away :-)